# Hi I am unable to crawl the data using the following csv file pattern ? any suggestions would really helpful

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

my csv file pattern .

```
00001000236^805^0013^48439-2518^02
```

i am trying to create a grok pattern for the above csv file format.

```
grok pattern:%[ ^ ][ ^ ][ ^ ][ ^ ]
```

Please let me know if i am missing something

Answer (score 0):

The separator, `^`, is a special character and needs to be escaped with a `\` every time it is referenced.

If you define a custom pattern `HATSEPERATED [^\^]*` then the grok expression that you want is `%{HATSEPERATED:A}\^%{HATSEPERATED:B}\^%{HATSEPERATED:C}\^%{HATSEPERATED:D}\^%{HATSEPERATED:E}`

The custom expressions is zero or more characters which are not the `^`.  See [Regexr](https://regexr.com/3turq) for an interactive explanation.

The Grok expression is just 5 columns separated by `^`.  Try using the [grok debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/) to try it out.  The names `A`,`B`,etc can be any word, so I'd recommend renaming them.